# Typescript filter values for dynamic property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to filter dynamic property from the list, How do I get positive value of dynamic property
I have a list of below properties.

Last 4 properties are not fixed.
Note A-1,Note A-1F,Note B-1,Note B-1F

```js
Applied: true
Comment: "Draw #01"
Date: Fri Dec 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
DealFundingID: "86d4b328-ca32-4ff9-bdf0-ec2705338342"
DealFundingRowno: 1
Issaved: true
WF_CurrentStatus: null
WF_CurrentStatusDisplayName: null
WF_IsAllow: 1
WF_IsCompleted: 0
WF_IsFlowStart: 0
WF_isParticipate: 0
Value: 885893.68
Note A-1: null
Note A-1F: 708714.94
Note B-1: null
Note B-1F: 177178.74
```

```js
var positiveItms = items.filter(i => colmname >= 0);
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How do i get positive value of dynamic property.

Comment: You have your input in a plain text format or you already converted it to a json array?

Comment: do you want to check all **prop** or some particular key?

Comment: I assume that your dynamic property is defined in variable `colmname` then try like `i[colmname] && i[colmname] >= 0` in `var positiveItms = items.filter(i => i[colmname] && i[colmname] >= 0);`. `i[colmname] &&` will first check if `columnname` property exists in `i` or not. If not then it will return `false`.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] as described in [ask]. Right now your example input seems to be plain text and not code. As @MarcellKiss asked: is your input really plain text?  Or is it some object and you're just showing us a serialized version of it?  Ideally you should give us code that we can drop into a standalone web IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) so we can demonstrate the issue for ourselves, and so we can test our own answers.  If you make it easy for people to help you, you will increase your chance of getting a good answer.  Good luck!